# React Conditional Rendering Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to understand using props with conditional rendering. I have a component called Intro.js inside my app.js.

My goal is to click a button on a form **in Intro.js** and remove Intro from app.js I've been able to accomplish this with a button *in app.js* but not within Intro.js. How would I get this to work within the child component Intro.js

```
        const [introSection, setIntroSection] = useState(false)

        {
        introSection ? <Intro /> : true
        } 

        <Button onClick={() => setIntro(false)}> Remove Intro Section</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your state update is also not aligned with the actual function. It should be `setIntroSection` instead of `setIntro`

```
<Button onClick={() => setIntroSection(false)}> Remove Intro Section</Button>
```

You're almost there with your logic. You just need to modify your logic like below

```
{
   introSection ? <Intro /> : null
}
<Button onClick={() => setIntroSection(false)}> Remove Intro Section</Button>
```

But this is not a good way when we have a very complex structure in the true path, so I personally prefer this way

```
{introSection && <Intro />} //when it's false, nothing is rendered
<Button onClick={() => setIntroSection(false)}> Remove Intro Section</Button>
```

If you want to do it inside `Intro`, you can pass a prop

```
<Intro isHidden={true} />
```

And in `Intro`, you can have this logic

```
const Intro = ({ isHidden }) => {
  if(isHidden) {
     return null
  }
  
  //true path to render your own component
  return <div></div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your setIntro/setIntroSection (it depends how you used it) function to Intro component as a prop, so then you will be able to access and use that state function. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use setIntroSection, not setIntro.

A whole bunch of code will be helpful to answer.